# Visual Studio requires windows 10?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I'm using windows 7 and I'm trying to learn C# using Visual Studio. If I try to make a new project it asks for a minimum and target version(The only options are windows 10). Afterwards, it tells me I can't open this kind of project without updating to windows 10. I can't update to windows 10, how can I use Visual Studio 2017 to make and compile a C# project on my windows 7 os?

I have the universal windows platform development installed. 
I'm trying to create a "Blank App(Universal Windows)".

[image]

Comment: What kind of project are you trying to create? If you are trying to create a UWP project, yes, Windows 10 is required.

Comment: If you are just trying to play with C#, make a Console Application. Or a Windows Form app.

Comment: Note to create a Windows form or console app you need to install the "desktop development" feature when installing vs2017

Comment: I have the universal windows platform development installed. I'm trying to create a "Blank App(Universal Windows)".

Comment: As already stated *Universal Windows* Applications (UWP for short) require Windows 10 - you need to try a desktop solution

Comment: A "Blank App(Universal Windows)" is for a UWP app, and UWP only runs on Windows 10. You'll need to do a console (reccomended), Windows Forms, WPF, or ASP.NET application.

Comment: I don't see an option to create a console application or windows form app. Is there something else I have to install before I can use those?

Comment: Templates > Visual C# > Windows Classic Desktop > Console App. Or use the search box at the top right of the window.

Comment: That's not an option on my window. I've attached a link to an image of my options in my original question.

Comment: Based on the screenshot you've posted, I suspect you need to run the Visual Studio 2017 installer and choose some additional options to install.

Comment: Do you have an idea of what I should be looking for? I have the "universal windows platform development" installed. I think I see it now, I believe it's the .NET desktop development package.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rerun the Visual Studio 2017 installer (you can re-obtain it from [here](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/) if you need to). Choose to modify your existing installation. Choose the ".NET Desktop Development" workload which will allow you to create console apps (best for playing with new programming languages), Windows forms, and WPF applications.

[image]

Once you've done that, launch Visual Studio 2017 and on the new project screen navigate to Templates > Visual C# > Windows Classic Desktop > Console App. Or search for "console".

You may also consider the ".NET Core cross-platform development" workload, which will let you create console applications that run on [.NET Core](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework#.NET_Core) instead of the full .NET Framework. This is newer and there's less documentation for it, but it's the future of .NET development.

Universal Windows Platform Development is for [UWP apps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Windows_Platform_apps), which require Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

1. Start the Visual Studio Installer
2. Select to Modify your current install.
3. Check the box for ".NET Desktop Development"
4. Click the "Modify" button

If you do not have the ".NET Desktop Development" component installed, you will not be able to create .NET applications that will run on previous versions of Windows.